# comparison between signed and unsigned char

Tags: c, for-loop, char, integer-promotion, relational-operators

I'm pretty much assuming this is a stupid question... but I can't really find the answer for it. So I'm asking this here.

For the purpose of learning about implicit type casting, I'm running the following code on C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char i;
    char cnt = -1;

    int a[255];

    for (int k = 0; k < 255; k++)
    {
        a[k] = k;
    }
    for (i = cnt - 2; i < cnt; i--)
    {
        a[i] += a[i + 1];
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran this program, nothing happened.

I was able to found out that the loop condition of for-loop was false at the first iteration, so the program exited the for-loop right away.

However, I don't get the reason why.

As far as I know, C does implicit casting when assigning or comparing variables with different types. So I thought that on `i = cnt - 2`, the minus operation makes the value -3, and then implicit casting assigns i with a value 253.

Then, shouldn't the condition `i < cnt` be true since (by another implicit casting of cnt because of comparison of signed and unsigned char) 253 is smaller than 255?

If it isn't, why is this false? Is there something that I missed or is there some exception that I don't know?

Comment: 253 is not smaller than -3 :) cnt data type is not unsigned char, just char -128 to 127. If u make unsigned char cnt = -1. It will works fine.

Comment: @Tevfik Kadan I'm kinda confused. It did worked when I did a same as you said, but shouldn't ```cnt``` be automatically casted into ```unsigned char``` and become ```255``` when doing ```i < cnt```? I just tried ```printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)253 < (char) -1)``` and it also gave false...

Comment: Both operands of the comparison are cast to `int`, with no intermediate step to `unsigned char` for `cnt` (or `(char)-1`).

Comment: Think of `i < cnt` as `((int) i) < ((int) cnt)`

Comment: Thanks! So unsigned char, short doesn't casts to char or short but casts to int...

Comment: Whether plain char is signed or not is implementation defined. *the purpose of learning about implicit type casting* There is no such thing as implicit type casting. All casting is explicit by definition. If you want to learn about implicit type conversions, the first thing to learn is to **avoid them at all costs**.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion - a lot of info, but the relevant parts: "Usual arithmetic conversions" applies to every `<` operator. When no floating point type is involved, case 4 there says integer promotions happen first. And integer promotions will promote both types to `int` (except on strange systems where `sizeof(char)==sizeof(int)`).

Comment: Refer to [this discussion on implicit type promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).  (As noted, _implicit_ casts are not a thing.  Casts are always explicit.)

Comment: This is a cast: (_type_). It is using the cast operator. That's the only cast that exist in C and it is always explicit by the programmer, triggering an explicit conversion. There are also various implicit conversions. But there are no implicit casts.

Comment: I have a vague memory that some post-K&R1, pre-C89 compilers *would* promote `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` to `unsigned int` instead of `int` (even if `int` could represent all the values of the original type). It's a bit of a pre-standard, grey area because K&R1 never included `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`, and `char` always got promoted to `int` whether or not it was unsigned.

Comment: This is C++ but I’d suggest you give it a watch, it will provide more insight than comments on here: https://youtu.be/iNeHHczBTIs

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. I was able to clarify the rule of implicit conversion and the difference of 'casting' and 'conversion'... I'm not sure if I  fully digested but was able to catch the point. I'll try understanding these fully as short as I can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not stupid at all. You were close to the solution: `i` is assigned the value `-3` but the implicit conversion to the type of `i`, `unsigned char`, changes the value to `253`.

For a more precise explanation, there are multiple issues in your test code:

- `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the platform and compiler configuration, so `char cnt = -1;` may store the value `-1` or `255` into `cnt`, or even some other value if `char` is unsigned and has more than 8 bits.
- The behavior of `for (i = cnt - 2; i < cnt; i--)` also depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned by default:

  - in all cases, the test `i < cnt` is evaluated with both operands converted to `int` (or `unsigned int` in the rare case where `sizeof(int)==1`). If `int` can represent all values of types `char` and `unsigned char`, this conversion does not change the values.
  - if `char` is unsigned and has 8 bits, `cnt` has the value `255` so `i` is initialized with the value `253` and the loop runs 254 times with `i` from `253` down to `0`, then `i--` stores the value `255` again into `i`, for which the test `i < cnt` evaluates to false. The loop prints `507`, then `759`, ... `32385`.
  - if `char` is signed and has 8 bits, as is probably the case on your system, `cnt` has the value `-1` and `i` is initialized with the value `-3` converted to `unsigned char`, which is `253`. The initial test `i < cnt` evaluates as `253 < -1`, which is false, causing the loop body to be skipped immediately.

You can force `char` to be unsigned by default by giving the compiler the appropriate flag (eg: `gcc -funsigned-char`) and test how the behavior changes. Using [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cjP86zWd7), you can see that `gcc` generates just 2 instructions to return 0 in the signed (default) case and the expected output in the unsigned case.

Comment: You have done a good job here of pointing out one of the unsettling things about the ambiguities of the `char` default  type in C.  I found [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default) on the topic  had a calming affect.

Answer (score 2):

For starters let's assume that the type `char` behaves as the type
`signed char`.

In this condition

```
i < cnt
```

the both operands are implicitly converted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions.

From the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, **the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed.**

and (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
> determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the
> specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real
> type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also
> the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the
> type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex
> otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> ...
> Otherwise, **the integer promotions are performed on both operands**. Then
> the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
> needed

and (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2. ...If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>    by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>    otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are called the
>    integer promotions**.

Thus the positive value of `i` represented like `0000 0000 1111 1101` after the integer promotions will be greater than the negative value `1111 1111 1111 1111`.

So the condition of the for loop at once evaluates to logical false because the positive value `253` of the type `int` is greater than the negative value `-1` of the type `int`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char cnt = -1;
    unsigned char i = cnt - 2;
    
    printf( "cnt = %x\n", ( unsigned int )cnt );
    printf( "i = %x\n", ( unsigned int )i );
    
    printf ( "i < cnt is %s\n", i < cnt ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
cnt = ffffffff
i = fd
i < cnt is false
```